# Are the distributions of uniform spanning trees unique up to graph isomorphism?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

I've tried to find any publications on this unsuccessfully, but maybe someone here has some ideas where to look.

Consider a directed graph $G = (V_G, A_G)$ of $N$ nodes and $M$ edges. Let $T_{N}$ denote the space of trees of up to $N$ nodes, unique up to isomorphism. Then we have $G$'s associated uniform spanning tree distribution $P_G: T_N \rightarrow [0,1], \sum_{t \in T_N} P_G(t) = 1$, which can be sampled by [Wilson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk).

Now consider a second graph $H = (V_H, A_H)$, again of $N$ nodes and $M$ edges, with uniform spanning tree distribution $P_H: T_N \rightarrow [0,1], \sum_{t \in T_N} P_H(t) = 1$. Then my question is, does there exists such a $H$ such that,

$\forall t \in T_N, P_G(t) = P_H(t)$

and $G \not\simeq H$. That is, is the distribution $P_G$ unique up to graph isomorphism? Or does there exist a counter-example?

Or equivalently, can any two non-isomorphic directed graphs be distinguished by their uniform spanning tree distributions given sufficient (possibly exponentially many) samples?

Thanks for any thoughts and references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two graphs are a counterexample:

[image]

For these graphs, not just the distribution but the multiset of spanning trees is the same, up to isomorphism. Both have the following $8$ spanning trees:

[image]